# Trouble understanding "Generics" example

Tags: c#, generics

I am going through a book trying to understand Generics with C# and I have come across an example I don't understand. Here is the sample code.

```
using System;

public class Printer
{
  public void Print<T>(T argument)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(argument.ToString());
  }

  static void Main(string[] arguments)
  {
    Printer printer = new Printer();
    printer.Print<string>("Hello, World");
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
    Console.ReadKey();
  }
}
```

What is confusing me is the  argument to the Print method. I understand using a generic type placeholder when dealing with a collections such as `List<T>`. However what I don't understand is how `<T>` comes into play with a method? Is the code just saying that the type of the parameter passed into the `Print()` method is just not known at design time and could be anything? Could someone help me decipher this? Thank you.

Comment: It's the worst example for demonstrating generics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By declaring your method with a generic type, you make your method more flexible as it can then work with variables of any type you choose, including primitive types (unless you specify `where T : class` of course).

Another *very* common example that *much better* illustrates one use of a generic method is a `Swap<T>(T, T)` method:

```
/* 
 * The ref keywords mean "pass by reference" i.e. modify the variables as they
 * were passed into the method.
 *
 * The <T> in the signature tells the compiler that T is a generic type, in case
 * the class itself doesn't already declare T a generic type.
 */
public void Swap<T>(ref T x, ref T y)
{
    // Tells the compiler that temp should be of the same type as x and y,
    // regardless of what type T may be
    T temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}

int x = 3, y = 6;
Swap<int>(ref x, ref y);
Console.WriteLine(x + " " + y);

char a = 'a', b = 'b';
Swap<char>(ref a, ref b);
Console.WriteLine(a + " " + b);
```

Comment: I don't know about common so much, I've never used Swap<T> in my almost 10 years of .Net development (well, to be fair generics came out in .Net 2.0, so only 8 years or so).  I also think having the ref parameters in there might be confusing to someone trying to understand the basics of template functions.

Comment: @SRM: It is common in example code at least... I edited my answer to annotate the `ref` keywords just in case.

Comment: I up-voted, I just wanted to point out a potential confusion point.  Good looking out with the comment.  I think you are right, I found a lot of examples that use Swap<T>.  It seems pretty ubiquitous - I've just never had the opportunity to use it.

Comment: @SRM: Me neither. Probably because it's a rather academic example :)

Comment: Where does the `Swap<T>` come into play? I see how T is used with the parameters but I still remain confused as to why there is a `<T>` after Swap. How would `Swap(ref T x, ref T y)` be any different?

Comment: @webworm: There is a local variable `temp` in the method. By declaring it a `T`, the compiler makes it the same type as the two parameters passed, *whatever the type may be*. You tell the compiler what type it is by passing the type generically, although in some cases the compiler is able to infer the type based on the parameters alone.

Comment: @BoltClock - Thanks for the clarification. I still remain confused as to why the `<T>` is needed in the declaration `public void Swap<T>(ref T x, ref T y)`. Wouldn't the line `T temp = x;` be enough to tell the compiler that the variable `temp` is the same type as the parameters, since they are defined as `T` also? I have never seen `<T>` used as part of the method name, rather I have only seen it used with parameters. Sorry if I am a bit "dense" on this? Generics have always been tough for me to wrap my brain around.

Comment: @webworm: `<T>` in the method signature tells the compiler that this is a generic method. The compiler only infers based on method calls, but you still have to tell it in the signature (`public void...`) that it's generic so it doesn't think `T` is some pre-defined type. This is particularly useful if you want to have generic methods in a non-generic class.

Comment: @BoltClock - That makes sense. Thank you so much for the original answer and your follow up to my questions also. Your explanations were very clear and concise. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Exactly what you wrote. Generic parameters are also possible at method level. They act exactly like on class level, just the scope of the type parameter is limited to the method.

Answer (score 3):

> Is the code just saying that the type of the parameter passed into the Print() method is just not known at design time and could be anything?

That's precisely what it's saying.  Now, whenever the compiler finds a reference to a T it will automagically substitute the type that was specified in the instance or method call (if the method is generic).  A prime example of that type of method is a pattern I've used (and seen used) many times.  It's basically a safe cast from one type to another.  The type you want to coerce to is specified as the generic parameter.  Example:

```
var something = SafeCast<int>("123.434"); // something == 123
var somethingElse = SafeCast<int>(23.45f); // somethingElse == 23
var somethingNull = SafeCast<int>(null);  // this shouldn't throw but return a null
```

Comment: +1 for excellent description. Your explanation really helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As the compiler does not know what T is, and T isnt defined at class-level, then the compiler needs to know what to cast the parameters to, thats where the  argument comes into play ;)